# Access Query: Parameterize whether or not to include field

Tags: sql, ms-access

At my job I often have to create Access queries that are customizable by the end user (without giving them access to the query builder.) I'm fine when it comes to passing parameters into the `WHERE` clause, but how can I let the user choose what goes into the `SELECT` and/or the `GROUP BY` clauses?

Currently, my solution is to collect the desired fields through a form, then rewrite the SQL of a saved query using `DAO.QueryDef` in VBA. But this is not ideal for a few reasons (needs to recompile every time, code can get pretty complex, etc.)

Anyone have any alternatives? Can anything be done with parameters here?

Comment: What are you referring to that *"needs to recompile every time"*?  The query plan?

Comment: I think so. I'm a little out of my depth here, but my understanding is that using parameterization allows the same query plan to be reused without the need to recompile. Which tends to mean the query runs a bit faster.

Comment: If you have in mind something like `SELECT [which_field] FROM MyTable` where `which_field` is a parameter whose value is the name of the column you want returned in the query result set ... then, no, that is not possible in Access SQL.  The closest you could get would be to feed the parameter to a `Switch()` expression which fetches the value from the target column.  But you couldn't adjust the column heading to indicate which column name is displayed.  Seems unsatisfactory to me.

Comment: Yeah. That's tricky too, because there is a variable number of columns they could select. But I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: The alternative is what you already do - using QueryDefs to modify saved query object.